# How is a gold rune different from a silver rune?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings

In this game, it's possible to earn runes and there are some special golden runes you earn by doing extra special stuff! Are the uses of the two types of runes different? So runes can be used to buy spells to help you out. Does this work in the same way even if the runes are gold instead of silver?

Note that what I call runes can also be considered shields/shield tokens.

The ISBN of this game is 978-1-58994-706-1 (this should help in distinguishing versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [similar question has been asked at BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1610161/gold-and-silver-runes):

The collected wisdom is:

> You can buy Gandalf cards with either the gold or the silver, or a combination of the two. Any time you need to discard runes, you can discard either or both.
>
> The silver runes are gained through the spaces on the board, and you always gain one rune per space. The gold runes are stacked face-down (or otherwise randomized) so that you do not know which value of rune you are getting until it is picked. Only a few spaces on the board have you picking a gold rune.
>
> Runes are good for scoring, Gandalf cards and can also be spend to avoid effects of at least one event. And 1 rune can be used to avoid a specific event tile (together with some other stuff). Might be some I have missed.

Comment: Cool, this was helpful! I'll see if any better answers come up before accepting and awarding bounties, but +1...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath, no problem, this was a simple google search. I have the game but have not played it for some time.

Comment: I can award the bounty in some hours, but it's coming!